# How to install a second Windows install on computer (on HDD2), but avoid the boot configuration of HDD1 to be modified?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I had:

```
Internal HDD1
Partition 1 100 MB: empty
Partition 2 150 GB: Windows 7 (BitLocker encrypted)
Partition 3 300 MB: BOOT 
Partition 4 700 GB: Data (BitLocker encrypted)

Internal HDD2
Empty
```

Then I installed Windows 10 *on HDD2* with a classical USB flash drive Windows 10 installer (coming from official ISO), but **I noticed it modified the boot partition of ... HDD1!**

i.e. if I remove HDD2 from computer, I still see a Windows 10 bootmenu when booting on HDD1 ; this confirms this installation **has modified HDD1 too**.

**Question: How to install Windows 10 to HDD2 of a computer, without modifying anything (especially not the boot sector / boot menu / boot partition) on HDD1?**

(Then you might ask: how would I boot on HDD2's Windows 10 then? I would like to do this rarely, but with the BIOS boot menu: `F12`: Boot on device: `HDD2`)

Comment: Whenever you install Windows, the installer will usually search for BCD stores on any connected disks, updating them automatically as a convenience for users to prevent the lay user unintentionally corrupting the BCD store, rendering the PC unbootable, if wanting to add the boot entry on their own.  A quick fix would simply be ensuring each HDD has it's own BCD file on the boot partition of HDD1 and HDD2, and if there are two, remove the BCD entry for Win10 from HDD1's BCD store using `bcdedit`.

Comment: Yes but when installing Windows 10 on hdd2 it even made my windows 7 from hdd1 unbootable because of bit locker : I had to insert a flash drive with a .bek file. So it really made a mess !

Comment: The easiest way would be to disconnect HDD1 beforehand then, as suggested in the answer below.  Even though this may be an inconvenience, you only have to do this once.  There's likely a more in-depth way to avoid this, and the best place I could suggest would be reviewing the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com) site.  On a side note, I would recommend disconnecting an encrypted disk anyways if installing Windows on a different disk, as it simply ensures issues don't arise with the encrypted partitions.

Comment: Since you opened a bounty, there are only two ways to do this, either: **(1)** Remove HDD1 prior to installing, which isn't an acceptable option; or **(2)** Use a custom `answer.xml` to modify the HDD the boot partition is created on to HDD2.  I don't have the time currently to write an answer on how to do so, but will in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks in advance @JW0914 for an answer about 2)! PS: I thought about 3) disable HDD1 from the ThinkPad T520 BIOS, but there is no option to disable indivual disk devices there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to unplug HDD1 during Windows 10 installation.

Alternatively, you can use EasyBCD from Windows 10 to change your boot partition as described [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/changing-the-boot-partition/), and then remove Windows 7 boot entries from Windows 10 and, vice versa, Windows 10 boot entries from Windows 7, using the same utility as described [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/deleting-entries/).

Comment: Yes I was thinking about this but I thought there is maybe an option which avoids to use a screwdriver?

Comment: Of course there is. But just unplugging the disc you don't want to be modified has the least chance to screw up.

Comment: (It's a laptop that's why I mentioned screwdriver)

Comment: @Basj opening up a laptop isn't really all that scary after the first time. I can really recommend it.  Just Do It! Only if it's just because of the dozen of youtubes about every type of laptop.

Comment: Yes indeed on my t520 it only takes 10 seconds, the hdd1 slot is very well placed. It's just a matter of having a small screwdriver around :)

Comment: @МаксимКорчагин Or maybe is there a way to totally disable internal HDD1 from BIOS for Thinkpad laptops?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and safest way to install Windows to a secondary disk HDD2,
without modifying absolutely anything on the primary disk,
is not to use your naked computer for the task.

In a nutshell, my idea is to install Windows into a virtual machine that
sees only one disk.

I can think here of two possibilities for this disk:

1. Assign HDD2 as the raw/physical disk of the VM.
2. Install to a virtual disk and then use a Virtual-to-Physical (V2P) utility
   to copy the virtual disk to HDD2.

The VM is only a tool here to create the disk. Once your physical disk
is created, you don't need the VM any more and can discard it.

To further develop these ideas, I would need to know more about your primary
operating system and which virtual machine products are possible on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (sorry I missed it in my notifications! I probably looked too fast). I am running both Windows 7 (Bitlocker protected) and Windows 10. What kind of VM system would you use?

Comment: Any major VM software would do that supports either raw disk of V2P, which is basically all of them. This method is totally safe and guaranteed not to touch any other disk on the computer.

Comment: I've used VirtualBox and QEMU the last days, but it was somehow slower than directly booting on them. Do you know a mode in which launching the VM would take all the resources of the current system and thus not being noticeably slower? Or are you referring to a different way of using a VM?

Comment: The VM is only a tool here to create the disk. Once your physical disk is created, you don't need the VM any more.

Comment: Oh that's right! It totally makes sense @harrymc, I'm going to try this!

Comment: Btw @harrymc I'm thinking about removing BitLocker from C:\ , it would solve the root problem of this question ("installing a new OS on HDD2 creates a mess on HDD1 because of BitLocker") ; if I manage to solve this: https://superuser.com/questions/1562888/bitlocker-unlock-d-with-a-unique-password-prompt-on-windows-start

Comment: Bitlocker with dual boot can be a disaster. It is something that I avoid - there are other methods.

Comment: Indeed @harrymc, that's why I would like to have c:\ non encrypted. But I'd like to have a prompt when Windows starts to ask the password to unlock data disk d:\  (if not, the desktop - stored in d:\desktop - and many other programs cannot be started), that's the problem here: https://superuser.com/questions/1562888/bitlocker-unlock-d-with-a-unique-password-prompt-on-windows-start

Comment: Thanks again @harrymc.

Comment: You're welcome, again.