# Unattended reboot on HDD2

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I know the problem since decades now: let's say **you want to reboot your computer on HDD2 or HDD3, to boot on another OS** than the main OS. You have to:

- Start menu > Restart computer
- Wait a few seconds for the shutdown + initial BIOS boot etc. (maybe 20 seconds?)
- Depending on your computer, press the <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>ThinkVantage</kbd> (for ThinkPads), <kbd>DEL</kbd> **at the right precise timing** after reboot to trigger the "Select the alternate device you want to boot on"
- Wait a few seconds
- Sometimes you have to press on another button (e.g. <kbd>F12</kbd> on my Thinkpad), and wait again
- Select the device on a menu
- etc.
- Sometimes you miss the precise timing, and you have to restart again!

**Question: is there a way to do it like this, e.g. from a script:**

- you select the device/partition you want to reboot on in a list, e.g. `"HDD2 / Partition 1 / Linux"` or `"HDD1 / Partition 2 / Windows 10"` or `"USB external (64 GB)"`
- then when you click "Go", you don't need to babysit the reboot and waste 1 minute of your life pressing keys at the right timing and waiting!

**?**

In my setup:

HDD1 Windows 7
HDD2 Windows 10
HDD2 another partition Debian Linux

Comment: You seem to have abandoned your [other post](https://superuser.com/questions/1499569/how-to-install-a-second-windows-install-on-computer-on-hdd2-but-avoid-the-boo).

Comment: @harrymc Oh right, sorry! I added a comment there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible if both current and target OS are using UEFI boot, using the EFI `BootNext` variable.

On Windows 10:

- Start menu → Settings → Updates & Security → Recovery → Advanced startup - Restart now → Use a device → (select OS to boot).
- Alternatively, Start menu → Power → <kbd>Shift</kbd> Restart → Use a device → (select OS to boot)

On Windows, using CLI:

1. `bcdedit /enum firmware` to list OS entries
2. `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence <GUID>` to select next OS by GUID

On Linux:

1. `efibootmgr` to list OS entries
2. `sudo efibootmgr -n <number>` to select next OS by number

Comment: Thanks! One of my machines is still Win7, is it possible too?

Comment: It should be via UEFI variables, but I don't think it's accessible in GUI.

Comment: Would you have an example @gronostaj of such variables, and where should I enter them? (in `cmd.exe`?)

Comment: Sorry, I have never done this in Windows.

Comment: I tried with WIN10, but I don't see "Use a device", I only see this: https://i.imgur.com/XOWqnCO.png. Even if I click on "Restart now", I don't see "Use a device"

Comment: @user1686 `bcdedit` only lists those: https://imgur.com/syIPEMF.png and not E: and F: from HDD2 which is still mounted and visible in Explorer (contains bootable Windows 10). Should I do something to add those? Or is because C: is on Windows 7, with no UEFI?

Comment: As I said it will work only if you're using UEFI boot both on current and target system. Lack of _Use a device_ option indicates that you're using a BIOS-compatible mode, not UEFI mode.

Comment: @Basj, but I wrote `bcdedit /enum firmware` in my edit. Without that option, you're looking at the Windows' own bootmanager within the current disk. That said, it might be possible to _add_ an OS from a different disk to it as well (i.e. add Win10 as a boot option to the Win7 disk, and add Win7 as a boot option to the WIn10 disk, etc.) essentially achieving the same thing in BIOS mode, but I don't have enough information about how to do that.

Comment: @user1686 I did a screenshot with `bcdedit` because it gave more info (2 paragraphs) than with `bcdedit /enum firmware` which gave only 1 paragraph of info. Do you think because both Win7 (HDD1) and Win10 (HDD2) are in BIOS Legacy and non UEFI?

Comment: @gronostaj I converted to UEFI with `mbr2gpt`, and now `Use a device` appeared, it's working indeed! It would be interesting to be able to script this `Settings > Updates & Security > Recovery > ... > Use a device > ATA HDD1` in one shortcut to easily reboot to another OS. Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: @Basj As I said, I've never done this in Windows. Manipulating EFI variables is definitely possible with Windows APIs, but you'll probably need administrative privileges.

Comment: Maybe there is a python module (cross platform) for this? I'll have a look @gronostaj. What would the relevant keywords for this specific uefi function?

Comment: @Basj The keyword is "efi variables". The variable you're interested in is called `BootNext`. This project looks interesting: https://github.com/geek1011/bootnext

Comment: @gronostaj Looks interesting indeed (I'll try to see if there is a Win7 version too). Or maybe this https://pypi.org/project/uefi-firmware/, but not sure because it does not seem to be able to manipulate UEFI variables: *"The UEFI firmware parser is a simple module and set of scripts for parsing, extracting, and recreating UEFI firmware volumes. This includes parsing modules for BIOS, OptionROM, Intel ME and other formats too"*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ideas in @gronostaj's answer, I just created a small tool for this purpose:
[Reboot Now!](https://github.com/josephernest/rebootnow)

It works by writing the UEFI `BootNext` variable, and it triggers a reboot.

Thus you can easily reboot to HDD2, an USB flash drive, or even to the BIOS Setup, directly from Windows.

[image]